# What is the exact meaning of read latencies in opscenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have OpsCenter 6.1 and I'm reviewing many metrics of a performance run (we're actually trying to view if striping our SSDs improves performance or not). When they run a test, I see the O/S Disk read latencies < 1ms, which seems good, so I'm happy with that. Now when looking at a few graphs in OpsCenter, I'm scratching my head. For example: The "TBL: Local Read Latency (cluster)" shows 50% percentile at 20 ms. The 90th percentile is at: 40 ms and 99th at 70ms. That seems horrible. There's another graph: "Read Latency Percentiles" that's even higher/worse. I believe the "non-local percentile" graph includes CF and networking times, which I guess could make sense (RF = 5 and CF=local_quorum so that would mean CF=3). So guessing for that one, we have some network latencies that maybe adding up to get the final answer. But what about the Local Read Latency? How is that 20 ms when the storage is responding in 1ms? Does that mean there is an average of 20 operations per request? The percentiles for SSTables read is 1-2 for the 90% percentile. Too many variations of these metrics to follow. Either way, I would expect a little faster response v.s. 70ms.

Comment: the cassandra open source project uses `read latency` to describe how much time the cluster spends responding to requests.  Can't speak to DS enterprise though.

Comment: There's a few latency points to be aware of. Latency at the application, the co-ordinator node and the local node. There will also be a variation here depending on the type an uniformity of your queries. For example if you are running a select by partition key vs a select *. Also how are you measuring your disk latencies?

Comment: I have a few tools for disk latencies - one of them is OpsCenter (they have a o/s disk latency measurement). I'm also running "iostat" every second to watch at that level as well. They seem decent. However, like I mentioned, when you look at , what I would guess would be "response", the latencies are huge (300ms-500ms). Network traffic is about 20MB-30MB/second, which is easily sustainable with the network configuration, but throughput is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not using datastax-enterprise and I can't speak to that.  Its probably worth understanding the cassandra Read path:

- Act as a coordinator.  Best case request the results from up to 3 nodes in your RF=5.
- Look through key cache (Memory request, if not load into memory)
- Load bloom filters into memory and run the bloom filters to verify if data is in the SSTable
- Look through tombstones.
- Load and use the indexes in the SSTable to try and find where your row is IN the sstable.
- Load the row/range of rows.

If this is a quorum request it will do this on multiple nodes.  If the nodes Disagree on results it will run a read/repair.

I personally wouldn't trust the metrics from Datastax enterprise for your read latencies.  Instead I would try measuring response times from your application layer.

Tuning you may want to consider:

- Increasing memory space for key cache
- Increase memory space for bloom filters so they get evicted less often
- If you're reading from the start/end of an SSTable row cache may help.
- If you're seeing many tombstones, you may be able to repair more often and decrease your `gc_grace_seconds`.

Comment: The latency measurements for DSE are the same as the ones used in COSS. While measuring latency from your application is a good overall strategy you still need the `proxyhistograms` and `cfhistorgrams` for the coordinator and table latencies to narrow down where you bottleneck might be